# Regexp for matching all @property in PHPDoc

Tags: php, regex

I am currently making regexp to extract all `@property` content in PHPDoc above class. I have no fields defined in class because i am using magic `__get()` method.

I have made `(?<=@property)(.+(?=))((?<= ).+)` regexp ([Live example](https://regex101.com/r/vh6MOi/7/))

But i can't cut out spaces around first group so if i have something like:

```
* @property string external_order_id
```

With regex i presented above i will get:

- Full match `string external_order_id`
- Group 1.   `string` (notice spaces around word)
- Group 2.   `external_order_id` (there is no unnecessary spaces)

I tried to use `(?= )` inside first group `(.+(?=))` but it stops regex after that match.

Can You help me with that? I would be thankful.

Comment: `.+` includes space, use `\w+` maybe? Or more explicitly defined range of values.

Comment: Try [`@property\s+\K(\S+)\s+(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/A0xQT8/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if You can add that: `@property *\K(\S+) +(\S+)` to answers I will accept You answer, because `\s` causes matching character from line below

Comment: You almost need `(?m)@property *\K(?>(\S+) *)??(\S+)$` otherwise groups will contain unexpected values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since properties with no type may exist you have to do this:

```
(?m)@property *\K(?>(\S+) *)??(\S+)$
                            ^^
```

- `(?m)` sets multiline flag
- `(?>...)` constructs an atomic group  that's used for its non-capturing purpose.
- `??` ungreedy optional quantifier (you may use `?` alone however)
- `$` asserts end of line

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/LlrdNq/1)

For now that you are familiar with end of line assertion you can use `\s` with no worries:

```
(?m)@property\s*\K(?>(\S+)\s*)?(\S+)$
```

Comment: Great! Right answer!

Comment: This way you are sure capturing group 2 will always contain property name.

Answer (score 2):

The whitespace lands in Group 1 since the `.+` captures those spaces that appear right after the `@property` substring (the lookbehind `(?<=@property)` finds a location right after `@property`, and `.` matches any chars but line break chars).

Besides, `(?=)` is redundant as it requires an empty string right after the current location, i.e. "does nothing".

You may use

```
(?m)@property\h*\K(?:(\S+)\h+)?(\S+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A0xQT8/6).

**Pattern details**

- `(?m)` - a multiline modifier making `$` match the end of a line rather than a whole string
- `@property` - a literal substring
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far from the Group 0 buffer
- `(?:` - matches a sequence of patterns:

  - `(\S+)` - Group 1: one or more non-whitespace chars
  - `\h+` - 1+ horizontal whitespaces
- `)?` - 1 or 0 times
- `(\S+)` - Group 2: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of a line.

Comment: Thanks! But `* @property *order_id*` is not matched :/ And it would be nice to have type alewys in first group and name in the second one, my initial regex did it almost fine :/

Comment: Then use `@property\h*\K(\S+)(?:\h+(\S+))?`

Comment: @Dominik Do you really need to only get the strings with 1 or 2 items after `@property`? Then as revo says, you need to add `$` with `m` option.

Comment: Unfortunately yes because property can has got type or not :/

Comment: Everything is fine, but not exactly in my case because I need type always in first group and name always in the second one, anyway Thank You for Your answer :)

Comment: @Dominik Note that any horizontal whitespace includes tab chars, and those will be matched with `\h`, not with `[ ]`